# OpenCV goodFeaturesToTrack in Obj-C-C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, opencv

I'm trying to iterate over the points i get from cv::goodFeaturesToTrack.

I retrieve my points using this code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f> > corners;
cv::goodFeaturesToTrack(image,corners, 500, 0.01, 10);
```

My idea, which doesn't work:

```
for (size_t idx = 0; idx < corners.size(); idx++) {
        cv::circle(image,corners.at(idx),radius,color,thickness);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you passing `corners` by reference ? If it is by value, then it doesn't even enter the loop. Try debugging the value of what `corners.size()` is.

Comment: The problem ist retrieving the cv::Point at idx … I'm entering the loop, but I cant access the right corner point. I'll give more detailed input, when I'm at the office

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The detector goodFeaturesToTrack (indeed all feature detectors) populate a vector of features, while you are trying to pass it a vector of a vector of features. The remainder of your code looks fine but you should change the line

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> corners;
```

to

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> corners;
```

and hopefully all will be well.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by "doesn't work". But, you might try looking at the [goodFeaturesToTrack_Demo.cpp](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/entry/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/TrackingMotion/goodFeaturesToTrack_Demo.cpp) to see if that usage will fix your problem.

**Update with code:**

```
/**
 * @function goodFeaturesToTrack_Demo.cpp
 * @brief Demo code for detecting corners using Shi-Tomasi method
 * @author OpenCV team
 */

#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

/// Global variables
Mat src, src_gray;

int maxCorners = 23;
int maxTrackbar = 100;

RNG rng(12345);
const char* source_window = "Image";

/// Function header
void goodFeaturesToTrack_Demo( int, void* );

/**
 * @function main
 */
int main( int, char** argv )
{
  /// Load source image and convert it to gray
  src = imread( argv[1], 1 );
  cvtColor( src, src_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );

  /// Create Window
  namedWindow( source_window, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

  /// Create Trackbar to set the number of corners
  createTrackbar( "Max  corners:", source_window, &maxCorners, maxTrackbar, goodFeaturesToTrack_Demo );

  imshow( source_window, src );

  goodFeaturesToTrack_Demo( 0, 0 );

  waitKey(0);
  return(0);
}

/**
 * @function goodFeaturesToTrack_Demo.cpp
 * @brief Apply Shi-Tomasi corner detector
 */
void goodFeaturesToTrack_Demo( int, void* )
{
  if( maxCorners < 1 ) { maxCorners = 1; }

  /// Parameters for Shi-Tomasi algorithm
  vector<Point2f> corners;
  double qualityLevel = 0.01;
  double minDistance = 10;
  int blockSize = 3;
  bool useHarrisDetector = false;
  double k = 0.04;

  /// Copy the source image
  Mat copy;
  copy = src.clone();

  /// Apply corner detection
  goodFeaturesToTrack( src_gray,
               corners,
               maxCorners,
               qualityLevel,
               minDistance,
               Mat(),
               blockSize,
               useHarrisDetector,
               k );


  /// Draw corners detected
  cout<<"** Number of corners detected: "<<corners.size()<<endl;
  int r = 4;
  for( size_t i = 0; i < corners.size(); i++ )
     { circle( copy, corners[i], r, Scalar(rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255)), -1, 8, 0 ); }

  /// Show what you got
  namedWindow( source_window, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( source_window, copy );
}
```

Comment: The link provided asks for a authentication, we need to register to see the code? Can you please post the example here.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! I have updated the link, and posted the code for posterity sake.